# Javascript - Managing time stamps from clients on a server

Tags: javascript, firebase, server, google-cloud-functions

I'm building an application where you can build a list of scheduled jobs. I store the timestamps on the server as ms since epoch.

A scheduled job has a start time and stop time.

I would like the server to run a function on the time stamps to tell whether or not it's time to run a scheduled job. But how can you make sure you're comparing server time relative to the clients timestamps?

Do you just store everything in UTC and save the users timezone? Then apply the offset of the timezone to get the ~time?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You can store the Date + Time as UTC so it's not aware of any timezone. In general backend services won't translate these timestamps to a given timezone. They'll be sent to a client which can do the translations to native date and time themselves.

You can also store the timezone ID to along with the timestamp so you can always derive the correct date and time from the stored value.

Comment: So, I can save the timestamp in UTC on the server along with the time zone. I will need to lookup the most accurate offset via some other api? What are the most common steps for this? I was expecting a lot of information on Stack, as it's not a very new thing someone would want.

Comment: The backend services most often don't to any transformations on the timestamp. Clients receiving the data can translate to their native timezone. I changes my answer a bit to clarify that part.